# Can't SetTextColor by Array on Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm new android. Can't convert from int to Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList. I don't understand this problem.

```
int[] colorsInactive = Resources.GetIntArray(Resource.Array.array_dot_inactive);



        for (int i = 0; i < dots.Length; i++)
        {
            dots[i] = new TextView(this);

            dots[i].SetTextColor(colorsInactive[currentPage]);
            dotsLayout.AddView(dots[i]);
        }
```

```html
Resource.Drawable.arrayAcdots
   <selector name="array_dot_inactive" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <item android:color="@color/dot_inactive_screen1"></item>
 <item android:color="@color/dot_inactive_screen2"></item>
 <item android:color="@color/dot_inactive_screen3"></item>
 <item android:color="@color/dot_inactive_screen4"></item>
</selector>
MainActivity
int[] colorsActive = Resources.GetIntArray(Resource.Drawable.arrayAcdots);
  int[] colorsInactive = Resources.GetIntArray(Resource.Drawable.arrayIndots);


  dotsLayout.RemoveAllViews();
  for (int i = 0; i < dots.Length; i++)
  {
   dots[i] = new TextView(this);
   dots[i].Text=(Html.FromHtml("&#8226;")).ToString();
   dots[i].TextSize=35;
   dots[i].SetTextColor(Resources.GetColorStateList(colorsInactive[currentPage],null));
   dotsLayout.AddView(dots[i]);
  }
```

Comment: `Resources#getColorStateList` ?

Comment: Warning CS0618: `Android.Content.Res.Resources.GetColorStateList(int)' is obsolete: `deprecated' 

After debug on device : Has been thrown
Resource ID #0xffd1395c

dots[i].SetTextColor(Resources.GetColorStateList(colorsInactive[currentPage]));

Comment: so use not deprecated version

Comment: I was looking for this problem on google  but it still get error.
dots[currentPage].SetTextColor(Resources.GetColorStateList(colorsActive[currentPage],null));

Comment: error? what error? how are you defining your `ColorStateList` in xml?

Comment: Updated xml file.

Comment: it is not `ColorStateList`, see https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList/

Comment: no non-static method "Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getColorStateList(ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;"

Comment: Ok. I will try it.

Comment: int[] colorsInactive = Resources.GetIntArray(Resource.Drawable.arrayIndots);

dots[i].SetTextColor(Resources.GetColorStateList(colorsInactive[currentPage],null));

Error: index ousite bound.... and colorsInactive is zero. it din't contain anything

Comment: how did you define your `ColorStateList` in xml? and what actually do you want to achieve? you have no states in your `ColorStateList` so why are you using `ColorStateList` at all? do you know the purpose of `ColorStateList`?

Comment: Ex: I want to set color for dots of each page. page 1 -> dot[0]-> #00000
page2->dot[1]->#FFFFF

Comment: I'm doing with intro slider

Answer (score 0):

This was a headache for me too. Since the more intuitive `GetColor(int)` was deprecated by Google, you **can't** do this anymore.

```
view.SetTextColor(context.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.color_name));
```

Instead you should use `GetColor(int, Theme)` in any of these ways

```
view.SetTextColor(context.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.color_name, null)); 
view.SetTextColor(context.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.color_name, theme));
```

However, this is only available from API 23 going forward, therefore if you want to support older devices, many Java developers will propose to use

```
view.SetTextColor(ContextCompat.GetColor(context, Resource.Color.color_name));
```

Now for us, Xamarin developers, this **won't** work either since it'll show an error saying that it can't convert `int` to `ColorStateList`. So, instead you should use

**SOLUTION:**

```
view.SetTextColor(ContextCompat.GetColorStateList(context, Resource.Color.color_name));
```

With this I think you can solve your problem.